# Data errrors Export Gridview to .txt in C#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to export data from a gridview which feed with a sql query. I have the data in the gridview as follows

```
id crédito   |  código |    Fecha                    |  Cliente                     |  Nro Identificación | Municipio   |   Valor   |   Saldo

78454        |  82025  |19/03/2011 12:00:00 a. m.    |  LÓPEZ LÓPEZ JAIRO ALBERTO   |   74322514         |    ARAUCA    |   1860000 |   620000
```

the drawback is that when you export them to .txt you throw them in this way
[image]

In other words, the tildes do not recognize me and neither does the ´ñ´.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
protected void ButtonGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string txt = string.Empty;

            foreach (TableCell rowtext in GridViewDatos.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                txt += rowtext.Text + ",";
            }

            txt += "\r\n";

            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewDatos.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell datos in row.Cells)
                {
                    txt += datos.Text + ",";
                }
                txt += "\r\n";
            }

            Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(txt);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=namefile_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".txt");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/text";
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Response.Output.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: **Hint:** You are using two different [Encodings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8). [UTF8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding?view=netframework-4.8) to encode the string, and [Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicodeencoding?view=netframework-4.8) to define the encoding of the stream.

Comment: removed leaving the UFT-8 and still not working

Comment: Hi, @JQSOFTT Add include its Response.Output.Write(txt,UTF8Encoding.Default);

Comment: What is the type of `Response`?